Install mcrypt extension on PHP 7.1.33 (with brew on MacOS Sonoma)
We have an old project using PHP 7.1.3 but
brew info shivammathur/php/php@7.1
gives
==> shivammathur/php/php@7.1: stable 7.1.33 (bottled) [keg-only]
So I try to make it works by installing the 7.1 package and setup the extension needed (note: we can not use Docker or other kind of VM, and this is the path we've choosen)
What I tried so far
cd /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin
PHPIZE=/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin/phpize PHP_CONFIG=/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin/php-config ./pecl install mongodb-1.6.0

The mongodb extension is finally installed
$ php71 -m | grep mongo
mongodb

The main issue is that the application uses mcrypt_decrypt function
Call to undefined function app\components\encryption\mcrypt_decrypt()

We have difficulties when forcing the PHP 7.1.33 to use mcrypt extension version 1.0.7
PHPIZE=/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin/phpize PHP_CONFIG=/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin/php-config ./pecl install --force mcrypt-1.0.7


The error message:
  273 |         php_mcrypt_filter_create
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [mcrypt_filter.lo] Error 1

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.
Edited:

using mcrypt_decrypt() alternative is my last option because it will break the production flow (DB migrate, etc). So, this question is not about asking an alternative to mcrypt.
I will post an answer.


Is there any reason why you update to an obsolete version to begin with? 7.4 or one of the 8.x versions should be your target. Anyhow, that "error message" has been trimmed too much to still be useful. Scroll further up and then throw the actual error message at a search engine or the search bar here.

This question is similar to: mcrypt is deprecated, what is the alternative?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

mcrypt was part of the 7.1 distribution. You can install it from source and specify --with-mcrypt when compiling.

Also see the changelog here -- you probably want v1.0.2 and not v1.0.7.

@AlexHowansky thank you very much for the clue, I will post an answer.

I realize that this brew tap has everything I need, and I don't need to install the old PHP extension using pecl or compiling from source.
https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-extensions
brew tap shivammathur/extensions
brew install shivammathur/extensions/mcrypt@7.1

Since I already have the old 7.4 mcrypt extension,
brew unlink mcrypt@7.4
brew link mcrypt@7.1 

Checking
php71 -m | grep mcrypt
mcrypt

